# $f(x+y+1)=\biggr(\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{f(y)}\biggr)^2$, find $f(x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math

Here is a simple yet a bit queer question.

Let $$f(x+y+1)=\biggr(\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{f(y)}\biggr)^2,$$

and $f(0)=1~~\forall ~x,y \in \Bbb R$.

**Find $f(x)$.**

I did some work on it and found $f(-1)=0$. A bit more grunt work and I also found the answer to be $(x+1)^2$ and checked it by plugging some numbers.

But I don't know how to solve it properly. I welcome some hints on how to proceed further.

Comment: Hello :) I assume $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, because otherwise some terms will not be well-defined. You can get a recursive formula $f(x+1)=(\sqrt{f(x)}+1)^2=f(x)+2\sqrt{f(x)}+1$. Maybe it is easier to define $g(x):=\sqrt{f(x)}$, then we have $g(x+y+1)=g(x)+g(y)$.

Comment: @Jochen yes, you are right $f(x) \ge 0$ for all real $x$

Comment: Ok, then I can prove $f(x)=(x+1)^2$ for all $x\in \mathbb Q$. Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @Jochen it's not mentioned in the source i am using but it seems safe to assume that it's continuous

Comment: I was doing an induction proof that only got to the integers, going to skip it since someone has the rationals  in progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the function $f_0:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $f_0(x)=(x+1)^2$ *isn't* a solution to this functional equation, at least not if the domain is $\mathbb{R}$. The reason is that in general $\sqrt{f_0(x)}=|x+1|$, and the absolute value becomes problematic. Indeed, the equation $f_0(x+y+1)=\left(\sqrt{f_0(x)}+\sqrt{f_0(y)}\right)^2$ is, after simplifying, equivalent to the equation
$$
(x+1)(y+1)=|x+1||y+1|,
$$
which fails exactly if $x<-1<y$ or $y<-1<x$. On the other hand, if we restrict $f_0$ to $[-1,\infty[$ or $]-\infty,-1]$, then the functional equation is satisfied.

The original problem actually admits no solution. Indeed, if we plug in $x=y=-1$, then we obtain $f(-1)=4f(-1)$, and hence $f(-1)=0$. But then if we plug in $x=0$ and $y=-2$, we have
$$
0=f(-1)=\left(\sqrt{f(0)}+\sqrt{f(-2)}\right)^{2}=\left(1+\sqrt{f(-2)}\right)^{2}.
$$
This implies $\sqrt{f(-2)}=-1$, which is impossible.

On the other hand, if we are interested in functions $f:I\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, where $I=[-1,\infty[$, which satisfy $f(x+y+1)=\left(\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{f(y)}\right)^2$ for all $x,y\in I$ as well as $f(0)=1$, then this admits a unique solution. Indeed, the function $g:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x-1)}$ is additive. Now if we define $G:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by the formula
$$
G(x)=
\begin{cases}
 g(x) &\text{if }x\geq 0\\
-g(-x) &\text{ else,}
\end{cases}
$$
then it is straightforward to prove that also $G$ is additive. Furthermore, $G$ is non-negative on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, and hence the graph of $G$ isn't dense. From the general theory around the Cauchy-equations, it follows that $G$ must be linear, i.e. of the form $G(x)=cx$ for all $x$, where $c$ is some constant. As $G(1)=1$, we obtain $c=1$, so $G(x)=x$ for all $x$. This then shows that $f(x)=(x+1)^2$ for all $x\in I$, and plugging this into the original equation shows that this is indeed a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x-1)}\ge0$. Then, the function $g(x)$ satisfies the equality $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$, with $g(1)=1$. This is exactly the famous [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).